# Checking if power is connected or not on android

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am working on an android project where I am registering a broadcast receiver in a class that extends BroadcastReceiver that receives intents for `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED`, `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED` and `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF`.

When these various intents are received it then calls functions within another class which extends `Service`.

When it receives the `ACTION_POWER_CONNECTED` it also calls a function called `isPowerConnected` that supposed to check whether the power is connected and if not it then enables the WakeLock.

The problem I am having is when I execute the `isPowerConnected` function it seems to work the first time but then every other time it receives:

> android.content.ReceiverCallNotAllowedException: IntentReceiver
>   components are not allowed to register to receive intents.

I have no idea how I can fix this. Below is the code for the isPowerConnected.

```
public boolean isPowerConnected()
{
    int pluggedIn = -1;
    try
    {
        Intent intent = context.registerReceiver(null, new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
        pluggedIn = intent.getIntExtra(BatteryManager.EXTRA_PLUGGED, -1);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log.e("IsPowerConnected", ex.toString());
    }
    return pluggedIn == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_AC || pluggedIn == BatteryManager.BATTERY_PLUGGED_USB;
}
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: If you are being told that you just plugged in, why do you want to check if you are plugged in again? You could also register for `ACTION_POWER_DISCONNECTED` and manage the state yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't register a new BroadcastReceiver in an existing BroadcastReceiver, which you are actually doing.

Comment: So how would I be able to check if the power is connected or not as that's what I need to be able to do

Comment: While you are unable to register broadcast receiver from broadcast receiver, there's nothing that would prevent your broadcast receiver to i.e. fire `IntentService` to do the registration which should work around this